# Converter for .MTS to MP3 or MP4

Tags: mp3, mp4, mts

Any free converters for .MTS to MP3 or MP4?

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: .MTS?  MPEG transport stream?

Answer (score 5):

For most conversion needs, I use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). It is free and available for OS X, Windows and Linux.

It handles a huge range of input and output formats, including reading MTS and outputting MP4.

There is a [step by step guide](http://www.macosvideoconverter.com/convert-video-on-mac-with-handbrake.html) that walks you through the GUI settings (it is for Mac, but the same principles apply on other OSes).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Windows OS, have a look at [iPodME](http://nodadev.wordpress.com/pc-projects/ipodme/), which is a small and elegant utility. I use iPodME for converting M2TS (AVCHD) files to MP4 files playable by iPhone and Android regularly with excellent results.

> iPod Media Encoder converts video into an iPod-compatible format, the easy way.
>
> As I was bored with the already existing converters like Videora, Xvid4PSP etc, I made this simple & efficient video converter. The profiles should be easy enough to figure, keeping in mind that slower encoding also means better video quality.
>
> The new video files are created by default in the same folder as iPodME.
>
> Features:
>
> - small (4 Mb), no setup, only 1 exe to put where you want, no codecs needed
> - based on ffmpeg
> - really easy to use and straighforward
> - easy batch encoding, just select multiple files by clicking on the “add files” button or drag’n drop them into the list
> - you can add new files to the batch during encoding
> - run in background without disturbing your work (with the defaut priority option)
> - 6 profiles adapted to most usage : 3 encoding speed, each optimized for file size or video quality
> - possibility to customize the encoding options
> - support soft-subtitles, and multiple subtitles per video
> - support multiple CPU cores automatically
> - can shutdown your computer after encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try [Free Video Converter](http://www.koyotesoft.com/indexEn.html#):

> Free Video Converter is a freeware
>   designed to convert all your Video
>   files. It supports to convert your
>   favorite video from/to AVI, MP4, iPod,
>   PSP, 3GP (mobile phone format), Zune,
>   iPhone, MKV, WMV, ASF, MOV, QuickTime,
>   MPEG, RM, VCD, AVCHD MTS, M2TS..

Answer (score 0):

Moyea [Video Converter](http://www.my-video-converter.com/video_converter/) is powerful in converting and editing almost all the formats like MTS, MKV, MOV, WMV, FLV, MP4, MPEG-2, DV, TOD, MOD, 3GP, OGG, FLAC, AC3, ACC, WAV, AVI, and etc.
Moreover, this program can guarantee the excellent audio and video for its advanced audio and video sync technology adopted.